# cxGrid Customize FocusRect draw

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I only want particulars columns on a focused row to have the focusRect on cxGrid(TableView). How do I do that? [image]

Comment: Probably best place to post such questions is support center of DeveloperExpress. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `OnCustomDrawCell` event of your tableview to customise the drawing. You can interrogate the `AViewInfo` parameter, which is of type `TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo` to determine if the cell is currently selected and how your cell will be drawn.